# Batch Execution possible in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have 30k rows of data in excel file, I need to figure out the values which are not present in database.
For this I have made an spring boot rest endpoint which reads the excel and queries the database. Is there any other solution possible because it is too slow and database connections gets exhausted serving 30000 data

Comment: Insert all data in temporary table, then `JOIN/EXISTS/EXCEPT`

Comment: you can also use table valued parameters OR put excel data into json and then use openjson to open it up

Comment: Use SSIS and use a Join Transformation in the Data Flow?

Comment: `database connections gets exhausted serving 30000 data`... are you closing connections (or at least returning them to the connection pool) when done processing each row?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes using connection pool but still getting :
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: comparatorPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 20074ms